# org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, integration-testing, ws-security

I would like to write a simple integration test with JUnit and Apache CXF to test some WS-Security-enabled services. While I try to run my code:

```
MyService myService = new myWsService(MY_SERVICE_WSDL).getMyWs()
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(myService);
Map<String, Object> ctx = ((BindingProvider) myService).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.callback-handler", new KeystorePasswordCallback());
ctx.put("ws-security.signature.crypto", new MyMerlinImpl());
```

Where MyMerlinImpl simply passes required Merln.* property values in overridden `loadProperties` method,

I get:

```
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}WssX509V1Token11 registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RequireIssuerSerialReference registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AlgorithmSuite registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Basic256Sha256 registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InclusiveC14N registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Layout registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Strict registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Wss11 registered.
sie 12, 2015 11:52:10 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl handleNoRegisteredBuilder
WARNING: No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}MustSupportRefIssuerSerial registered.

org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
```

What am I doing wrong? These seem to be rather standard policies... In fact, I use the same code on a JBoss EAP 6.1 WS client and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by adding WSS4JOutInterceptor. It seems that in JBoss this interceptor is added automatically...

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(myService);
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint()
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor())
```

Answer (score 9):

Do you have the cxf-rt-ws-security jar on the classpath?

Colm.

Comment: it is this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-security/3.2.0

Comment: always worth a check. in my case, i dismissed this possibility right away, but to my horror, after an hour or so of searching other causes, this was the case indeed.

Comment: I was facing the same exception "org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.", setting the httpConduit and policy for the client didn't fix it, however it worked after adding this dependency. I believe it is related to the dependent transport and policy modules which are bundled in the " cxf-rt-ws-security". thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by Chetan works, however, if you are getting error for multiple  policies you need to add them in a Set

```
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = 
    org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();


    Bus bus = client.getBus();
    PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry reg = bus.getExtension(PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry.class);
    Set <QName> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "IncludeTimestamp") );
    set.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "TransportBinding"));
    reg.register(new IgnorablePolicyInterceptorProvider(set));
```

[This link explains the solution in detail](http://littlebigextra.com/fix-org-apache-cxf-ws-policy-policyexception-policy-alternatives-can-not-satisfied/)

Answer (score 1):

My own two cents : in my own special scenario (JAX-WS, WS-Security, WS-SecurityPolicy), this error was occuring when doing client.getConduit(), like below:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
```

The above code was running without throwing any exceptions (although I had other problems later), when using Apache CXF 2.7.18 - I started to have problems with assertion builder when upgrading to Apache CXF 3.0.16. Now cxt-rt-ws-security JAR WAS on the classpath, but it seems that WSS4J in this version of CXF was split into multiple JARs, therefore I had to include wss4j-policy JAR from the CXF downloaded bundle to the classpath.

The error remained the same, but at least a long string of WARNings from assertion builder disappeared (No assertion builder for type T registered), being replaced now by:

> 13:45:55,723  WARN WSSecurityPolicyLoader,main:112 - Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: org/apache/wss4j/dom/handler/WSHandler
>
> 13:45:55,753  WARN WSSecurityPolicyLoader,main:112 - Could not load or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: org/apache/cxf/ws/security/wss4j/PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor

To make the story short, I received other warnings (I was finding the JARs by doing a blind grep inside the lib directory of the CXF bundle, and including them one by one),
and ended up including all wss4j-*.jar files

And the call to getConduit() now passes at least. Whew.

Comment: which version of WSS4J did you use?  Because I am using the latest version (CXF 3.3.2 and WSS4J 2.2.3) but they are not supporting the old namespace:  {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512}SupportingTokens .    The version 2.2.3 of WSS4J is only supporting this: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SupportingTokens

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can disable policy check like this:

```
    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        SpringBus springBus = new SpringBus();
        var e = new PolicyEngineBPDefinitionParser.PolicyEngineConfig(springBus);
        e.setEnabled(false);
        springBus.getFeatures().add(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Policy defined in the WSDL file is non standard, then CXF will not be able resolve it.Hence the error.

There are two way - 
Either you can ignore it (if its okay to ignore)
or provide an alternate provider.

To ignore - create an instance of IgnorablePolicyInterceptorProvider and register it.

Below is example for ignoring NtlmAuthentication policy if defined in your WSDL.
Note: NtlmAuthentication should be handled differently than setting soap header.

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
                  Bus bus = client.getBus();
                  PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry pipr = bus.getExtension(PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry.class);

QName ntmlIgnore = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http", "NtlmAuthentication");
interceptorRegProvider.register(new IgnorablePolicyInterceptorProvider(ntmlIgnore));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bus.getExtension(PolicyEngine.class).setEnabled(false);
```