# CXF Policy Validator disable

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security

all.

I'm interacting with a webservice that's requires signature and policy.

I set up my CXF (3.1.6 wildfly bundled) with binding provider properties, callback handler, keystore ect.

```
bp.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, new PasswordCallbackHandler());
                bp.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, MyUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("crypto.properties"));

bp.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_USERNAME, "client");
```

CXF takes care to provide all necessary policy defined in the wsdl.
The comunications goes well, I send the request and receive the expected response.

But at this point the CXF Policy validator throws an exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts: Soap Body is not SIGNED
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.handle(PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
```

This is the contract for the signed parts:

```
    <sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:Body />
        <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="ReplyTo" />
        <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />            
        <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
        <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="Action" />
        <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />

    </sp:SignedParts>
```

This is received response:

```
...
      <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse S"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_5002">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>IirHgSUh19ly5qpPiXKVfMB2tZ4=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_5003">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>8SY6Wz36TUlZtY+31Z5EpESs5JM=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_5004">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>yvxtMZ3SC++ZOv0RPS/Ge9ETGHA=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_5005">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>t/slFuF8/W8sWGrrAuJTmtliCeU=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_5006">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>Cjcz1r8PMjV/04CLrMDpNx+e3ks=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_3">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsu wsse S"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>6htA73nOJBrYMteWrJ9pdag3cA8=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
     ...

  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:getCallResponse xmlns:ns2="http://somenamespace/Schemas/" wsu:Id="_5006">
```

As you can seen there is a reference to the signed part   but the ID attribute is not at the body (like for the request) level but on the child tag.

I don't know if this can be the problem, if so is a server side problem but the service is legacy and there's no way to change it.

So my question is: how I can disable the incoming policy validator or the specific assertion on SoapBody?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962342/org-apache-cxf-ws-policy-policyexception-none-of-the-policy-alternatives-can-be for more actual solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Following the Colm O hEigeartaigh help, this is the resolution implemented.

Properties setup:

```
 // Policy ovveride
        Map<QName, SecurityPolicyValidator> validatorMap = new HashMap<>();
        validatorMap.put(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "SignedParts"), new FakeSecuredPartsValidator());
        bp.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.POLICY_VALIDATOR_MAP, validatorMap);
```

Fake validator based on the original one in CXF:

```
public class FakeSecuredPartsValidator implements SecurityPolicyValidator {

 private CoverageType coverageType = CoverageType.ENCRYPTED;

    /**
 * Return true if this SecurityPolicyValidator implementation is capable of validating a
 * policy defined by the AssertionInfo parameter
 */
@Override
public boolean canValidatePolicy(AssertionInfo assertionInfo) {
    if (coverageType == CoverageType.SIGNED) {
        return assertionInfo.getAssertion() != null
            && (SP12Constants.SIGNED_PARTS.equals(assertionInfo.getAssertion().getName())
                || SP11Constants.SIGNED_PARTS.equals(assertionInfo.getAssertion().getName()));
    } else {
        return assertionInfo.getAssertion() != null
            && (SP12Constants.ENCRYPTED_PARTS.equals(assertionInfo.getAssertion().getName())
                || SP11Constants.ENCRYPTED_PARTS.equals(assertionInfo.getAssertion().getName()));
    }
}

/**
 * Validate policies, set all as validates
 */
@Override
public void validatePolicies(PolicyValidatorParameters parameters, Collection<AssertionInfo> ais) {
    //
    // SIGNED_PARTS and ENCRYPTED_PARTS only apply to non-Transport bindings
    //
    if (isTransportBinding(parameters.getAssertionInfoMap(), parameters.getMessage())) {
        return;
    }

    // Set asserted = true for all Assertions
    for (AssertionInfo ai : ais) {
        if (ai.isAsserted()) {
            // Secured Parts could already have been asserted by one of the other validators, if
            // they are a child of a SupportingToken
            continue;
        }

        ai.setAsserted(true);
    }
}

private boolean isTransportBinding(AssertionInfoMap aim, Message message) {
    AssertionInfo symAis = PolicyUtils.getFirstAssertionByLocalname(aim, SPConstants.SYMMETRIC_BINDING);
    if (symAis != null) {
        return false;
    }

    AssertionInfo asymAis = PolicyUtils.getFirstAssertionByLocalname(aim, SPConstants.ASYMMETRIC_BINDING);
    if (asymAis != null) {
        return false;
    }

    AssertionInfo transAis = PolicyUtils.getFirstAssertionByLocalname(aim, SPConstants.TRANSPORT_BINDING);
    if (transAis != null) {
        return true;
    }

    // No bindings, check if we are using TLS
    TLSSessionInfo tlsInfo = message.get(TLSSessionInfo.class);
    if (tlsInfo != null) {
        // We don't need to check these policies for TLS
        PolicyUtils.assertPolicy(aim, SP12Constants.ENCRYPTED_PARTS);
        PolicyUtils.assertPolicy(aim, SP11Constants.ENCRYPTED_PARTS);
        PolicyUtils.assertPolicy(aim, SP12Constants.SIGNED_PARTS);
        PolicyUtils.assertPolicy(aim, SP11Constants.SIGNED_PARTS);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public CoverageType getCoverageType() {
    return coverageType;
}

public void setCoverageType(CoverageType coverageType) {
    this.coverageType = coverageType;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The service is not following the spec, the Body element itself must be signed, and not the child Element as in the request above. However, recent versions of CXF allow you to plug in custom validation logic via the "ws-security.policy.validator.map" JAX-WS property. This is a map which maps a QName to a SecurityPolicyValidator instance. So in your case you can map to SignedParts policy QName to a modified version of the default SecuredPartsPolicyValidator to change the validation logic.